# ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified

Tags: sql

Cannot get this SQL Query to work. I have tried everything.

I am making it a cast cause i want the order by to work with numbers in nvarchar.

For example I want it to do this:

> 5  6  7  8 9  10 11 101

instead of

> 5 6 7 8 9 10 101 11

```
 SELECT DISTINCT StoreNumber, StoreNumber + ' -- ' + StoreName as
 StoreName FROM tbl_PUSH_STORES WHERE StoreNumber IS NOT NULL ORDER BY
 CAST(StoreNumber AS INT) ASC
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! This isn't a great question for StackOverflow, and you seem to be having general issues with asking questions on this site. I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have a specific, programming-related question.

Comment: I am fixing my question

Comment: Is the error you are receiving the title of this post? If so, why not `CAST()` your `StoreNumber` in your SELECT clause to an `INT` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT StoreNumber, ...
```

with this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(StoreNumber AS INT) as StoreNumber, ...
```

See here : [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7bf6f/6)